# Splitting a string on whitespace while ignoring specific whitespace

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a string on all whitespace except for whitespace preceded by a comma.

Example:

```
"abc de45+ Pas hfa, underak (333)"
```

would split to:

```
Item 1: abc
Item 2: de45+
Item 3: Pas
Item 4: hfa, underak
Item 5: (333)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, As stackoverflow is not a code writing service , kindly show your efforts in question by adding source code of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

You should split by `(?<!,)\s`
Check here : https://regex101.com/r/9VXO49/1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split only at a space, then simply use `split()`

```
a = "abc de45+ Pas hfa, underak (333)"
split_str = a.split(' ')    #Splits only at space
```

If you want to split at spaces but not period, as suggested by @Beloo, use regex

```
import re

a = "abc de45+ Pas hfa, underak (333)"
split_str = re.split(' ' , a)    #Splits just at spaces
split_str = re.split('[ .:]', a)    #Splits at spaces, periods, and colons
split_str = re.split('(?<!,)[ ]' , a)    #Splits at spaces, excluding commas
```

As you might have guessd, if you want to exclude a character, simply put it in between the `(?<!` and `)`

Comment: your regex output gives `['abc de45+ Pas hfa, underak (333)']`

Comment: @R S Nope now it gives `['abc', 'de45+', 'Pas', 'hfa,', 'underak', '(333)']`  OP specifically mentioned he do not want to split at comma.

Comment: Aah thanks for pointing it out. I assumed he meant just comma and not comma+space. Made the changes.